# How would I convert this bash script to pure bourne-shell?

Tags: bash, sh

I'm not well versed in either language so I need some help in determining which parts of this script contain "bashisms" or bash-only syntax that could error on a pure bourne-shell interpreter.

```
#!/bin/sh
RUNDIR=".run.%SSH_LONG_ID%"
TMPDIR="/tmp/$RUNDIR"

mkdir $TMPDIR
cd $TMPDIR

####################
# Create 'stub2' script
####################

sed 's/^   //' >stub2 << 'MARKITEIGHTDUDE'
   #!/bin/sh
   #

   TMPDIR=`pwd`
   touch running
   sh command
   echo $?
   cd $TMPDIR
   rm -f running
MARKITEIGHTDUDE

####################
# Create 'command' script
####################

sed 's/^   //' >command << 'MARKITEIGHTDUDE'
   #!/bin/sh
   #
   TMPDIR=`pwd`
   %SNCCOMMAND%
MARKITEIGHTDUDE

####################
# Create 'complete' script
####################

sed 's/^   //' >complete << 'MARKITEIGHTDUDE'
   #!/bin/sh
   #

   if [[ $0 == '/'* ]]; then
           TMPDIR="`dirname $0`"
   else
           TMPDIR="`pwd`"/"`dirname $0`"
   fi

   STATUS=`tail -n 1 $TMPDIR/nohup.out`
   sed '$d' < $TMPDIR/nohup.out > $TMPDIR/nohup.out2
   mv $TMPDIR/nohup.out2 $TMPDIR/nohup.out
   cat $TMPDIR/nohup.out
   rm -f $TMPDIR/nohup.out
   rm -f $TMPDIR/stub2
   rm -f $TMPDIR/complete
   rm -f $TMPDIR/command
%ADDITIONALFILES_REMOVE%
   rmdir $TMPDIR
   exit $STATUS
MARKITEIGHTDUDE

####################
# Create additional scripts
####################

%ADDITIONALFILES_ADD%

##

RESULT=`nohup sh stub2 1>$TMPDIR/nohup.out 2>$TMPDIR/nohup.out2 3>/dev/null &`
sleep 1
echo "sncrun:$RUNDIR"
exit 0
```

I think that the [[ ]] syntax is only bash but is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: Your script is full of unquoted variables. This does not answer your question, but it is worth mentioning.

Comment: FYI, `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh, not Bourne shell, on modern platforms. They're literally decades apart -- Bourne dates to the 70s, POSIX sh dates to the early 90s (and was derived from ksh of the time, not directly from Bourne).

Comment: HEREDOCS provide a method for indentation that allows you to remove the sed.  If you do `cmd <<- LABEL` (note the hyphen after the `<<`), leading indentation will be stripped.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The only changes that immediately stand out are:

```
if [[ $0 == '/'* ]]; then
```

change to

```
firstchar=`sed -e "s/\/.*$/\//" <<< $0`
if test "$firstchar" = "/"; then
```

double check at [Difference with borne shell](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell.html)

Comment: Thanks, thats what I figured too.

Comment: I don't believe that ``==`` existed.

Comment: `==` is indeed a bashism (use `=` instead), but also the standard `test` (aka `[ ]`) command doesn't do wildcard matching.

Comment: -1, factually incorrect; those two expressions aren't equivalent.

Comment: It is now fixed, sorry I overlooked it, please unding

Comment: Still showcasing bad practices here: `echo $0` is not the correct way to emit `$0` byte-for-byte; globs are expanded, runs of whitespace changed to single spaces, etc when quotes are not used, and some implementations of `echo` will simply remove any leading `-E` or `-n`; safer to use `printf '%s' "$0"`. Also, you can get only the first character of a string using only parameter expansions available in POSIX sh -- no need for an expensive subshell and pipeline, or thus for `sed` to be involved at all.

Comment: I agree with your statements, but for stripping the first char, none are relevant.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy why not just eliminate the pipe as a best practice?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, re: eliminating the pipe, I believe I suggested that (by using parameter expansion). It's important to also eliminate the subshell as well, though -- if you're using backticks or `$()`, that's still a hefty unnecessary performance hit.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, ...also, `<<<` isn't available in POSIX sh.

Comment: ...as for whether those practices are relevant, it depends on what the string _is_. If it's `* /hello` (which, though bizarre, _is_ a possible value -- `argv[0]` is set by the calling program, and thus can be completely arbitrary).

Answer (score 1):

The `[[ ]]` test is the only bashism I see, but it's not trivial to replace that in a posix-shell-compatible script. The two options I see are to use `case`:

```
case "$0" in
    "/"*)
        TMPDIR="`dirname $0`" ;;
    *)
        TMPDIR="`pwd`"/"`dirname $0`" ;;
esac
```

...or use slightly weird matching trick in a shell expansion:

```
if [ "${0#/}" != "$0" ]; then
```

The way this works is that `"${0#/}"` expands to `$0`, but with a leading "/" removed (if there is one). It then compares that with just `"$0"`, and if it's different (`!=`), then `$0` must've started with "/".

BTW, as Aleks-Daniel Jakimenko pointed out, there are a lot of variable references that aren't double-quoted, which can cause trouble in some cases (e.g. spaces in filenames). Fixing this is nontrivial, because double-quotes must be escaped between backquotes. If you care about this, I'd recommend first replacing all the backquotes with `$( )` (which is in the posix standard, so it should be portable). Then you can nest double-quotes cleanly, as in `TMPDIR="$(pwd)/$(dirname "$0")"` (note: I also left the `/` inside the double-quotes -- this doesn't actually matter, I just find it easier to read).

BTW2, is there any reason to capture the (nonexistent) output of the `nohup`ed command near the end? That is, why not replace

```
RESULT=`nohup sh stub2 1>$TMPDIR/nohup.out 2>$TMPDIR/nohup.out2 3>/dev/null &`
```

with just

```
nohup sh stub2 1>$TMPDIR/nohup.out 2>$TMPDIR/nohup.out2 3>/dev/null &
```

Comment: +1: Accurate, efficient, and (if the advice at the end is followed) fixes some potential bugs caused by the attempted unnecessary command substitution. Might stand to add some more quotes (what if `$TMPDIR` expands to contain whitespace? Likewise for `$0`; might also change backticks to use the non-deprecated `$()` syntax, which is fully supported in POSIX sh).

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear now-a-days that such a thing as "pure Bourne shell" even exists. You can write your shebang as /bin/sh to enforce "sh only" mode, but really it just forces POSIX compliance. However, this might get you what you're looking for in a general sense.

For more information, you can check the following two sources:

http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/bashref/BashPOSIXMode.html

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44836/when-sh-is-a-symlink-to-bash-or-dash-bash-limits-itself-to-posix-compliance-so

Comment: -1, doesn't answer the question, and not particularly accurate. There may exist no completely compliant implementation of POSIX sh, but that's irrelevant to porting a script to depend only on facilities it standardizes. By contrast, if the questioner truly meant Bourne, the Heirloom implementation is actively maintained (for portability to modern platforms -- obviously, no feature development takes place) and considered canonical.

Comment: Correct @Charles, which is why I suggested running the script in a POSIX only shell (or mode thereof), as this will show him in future scripts what is "Bourne only", rather than actually answering his question by pointing out the particular facets of this one script. I like to call that, "teaching a man to fish." This one script is also not very useful to future users of SO from a knowledge perspective, but showing where some of the pitfalls are of the larger question behind his question is.

Comment: If what you have isn't an answer but a comment or an aside, that's what the comment system is for.

Comment: ...also, the "POSIX-only" mode of most shells (particularly including bash) is actually a rather large superset, so using it is **not** in fact an effective way to determine compliance. ash gets closer than many, but even that supports things (such as the `local` keyword) that aren't in the baseline POSIX standard.